# How to create a new Zabbix event from Ruby script?

Tags: ruby, zabbix

Is this possible to generate a new Zabbix event from a Ruby script? I was suggested to use [zabbix_sender](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manpages/zabbix_sender) script, but I couldn't find any example.

Also, I couldn't find any API related to the [events](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/api/event) creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create some item of type zabbix trapper and then you can send some values to its name by zabbix_sender. You can send one value, or more collected data with timestamps. [Here are docs](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/concepts/sender).

Alternatively you can write own zabbix trap sender. [Protocol](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/protocols) is quite easy. I done the same in Python... no external commands.

Answer (score 1):

Zabbix API does not allow item value updates by design.

I have investigated couple options* and my preferred way to update Zabbix item value from Ruby is using this approach found in [miyucy's gist](https://gist.github.com/miyucy/1170577):

Example with simple error handler:

```
s = Zabbix::Sender.new 'zabbix_server', 10051

zabbix_resp = s.send('host', item_key, value)

if zabbix_resp["response"] != "success" or zabbix_resp["info"].split(';')[1] != " failed: 0"
  puts "error: zabbix responded with #{zabbix_resp} when trying to update #{item_key}"
end
```

*One example of alternative way - [calling zabbix_sender binary](http://www.108.bz/posts/it/parallel-http-monitoring-with-ruby-and-zabbix/)